# matching text EXACTLY within vba IF statement

Tags: vba, string-matching

I looked through the questions here and though there is a lot of stuff about matching similar strings with the instr function etc, there isn't much about exact matching.

I'm looping through a list of names classified by id where each id has its own corresponding benchmark. Unfortunately all the benchmark names are something along the lines of "Barclays" x Index where there are a ton of similar sounding names such as Barclays US Aggregate Index, Barclays Intermediate Us  Aggregate Index etc... and just trying to match gives an output.. but the wrong data points. Here is my code for reference.. the issue is in 2nd elseif of the loop.

I was wondering if there is an easy method to resolve this.

```
For i = 1 To lastrow
Sheets(source).Activate

If source = "Historical" Then
        If Range("A" & i).Value = delimit2 Then
                benchmark_name = Sheets(source).Range("L" & i).Value
                j = j + 10
                name = Sheets(source).Range("A" & i + 1).Value
                Sheets(output_sht).Range("D" & j - 3) = "Portfolio"
                Sheets(output_sht).Range("E" & j - 3) = benchmark_name

        ElseIf benchmark_name <> vbNullString _
        And Range("A" & i).Value = benchmark_name Then
                If IsNumeric(Sheets(source).Range("F" & i).Value) Then
                    Alt_return3 = Sheets(source).Range("F" & i).Value
                    If IsEmpty(Sheets(output_sht).Cells(j, col1)) Then
                    Sheets(output_sht).Cells(j, col1) = Alt_return3 / 100
                    End If
                End If

                If IsNumeric(Sheets(source).Range("G" & i).Value) Then
                    Alt_return5 = Sheets(source).Range("G" & i).Value
                    If IsEmpty(Sheets(output_sht).Cells(j + 1, col1)) Then
                    Sheets(output_sht).Cells(j + 1, col1) = Alt_return5 / 100
                    End If
                End If
               '
                If IsNumeric(Sheets(source).Range("H" & i).Value) Then
                    Alt_returnINC = Sheets(source).Range("H" & i).Value
                    If IsEmpty(Sheets(output_sht).Cells(j + 2, col1)) Then
                    Sheets(output_sht).Cells(j + 2, col1) = Alt_returnINC / 100
                    End If
                    Sheets(output_sht).Range("D" & j & ":E" & j + 5).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
                End If

            Sheets(output_sht).Range("C" & j) = period
            Sheets(output_sht).Range("C" & j + 1) = period2
            Sheets(output_sht).Range("C" & j + 2) = period3
        Else

        End If
End If

Next i
```

Comment: Currently your loop does nothing if `source` does not equal `Historical`. Is this intended behaviour or should your `ElseIf` actually be `Else` <newline> `If`?

Answer (score 0):

I know you are looking for an exact match. However you may want to consider trying a FuzzyMatch.

http://code.google.com/p/fast-vba-fuzzy-scoring-algorithm/source/browse/trunk/Fuzzy1

You can download/import this function to your workbook and then call it with the 2 strings/names you are comparing and it will return a score.

If I were you I'd loop through all the possible names and take the highest score.
Which in your case would be 100% if you are looking for an exact match.

This will add time to your procedure but it might help you.

===EDITED

========= Here is the code. Add this to your Module.

```
Option Explicit
Public Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32.dll" () As Long
'To be placed in the Declarations area
'_____________________________________
Sub TestFuzzy()
Dim t As Long, a As Long, i As Long
t = GetTickCount
For i = 1 To 100000
a = Fuzzy("Sorin Sion", "Open Source")
Next
Debug.Print "Similarity score: " & a & "; " & i - 1 & " iterations took " & _
GetTickCount - t & " milliseconds"
End Sub

'TestFuzzy's result should look like:
'Similarity score: 0.3; 100000 iterations took 2094 milliseconds
'The test was done on an Intel processor at 3.2GHz
'_____________________________________

Public Function Fuzzy(ByVal s1 As String, ByVal s2 As String) As Single
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, d1 As Integer, d2 As Integer, p As Integer
Dim c As String, a1 As String, a2 As String, f As Single, o As Single, w As Single
'
' ******* INPUT STRINGS CLEANSING *******
'
s1 = UCase(s1) 'input strings are converted to uppercase
d1 = Len(s1)
j = 1
For i = 1 To d1
c = Mid(s1, i, 1)
Select Case c
Case "0" To "9", "A" To "Z" 'filter the allowable characters
a1 = a1 & c 'a1 is what remains from s1 after filtering
j = j + 1
End Select
Next
If j = 1 Then Exit Function 'if s1 is empty after filtering
d1 = j - 1
s2 = UCase(s2)
d2 = Len(s2)
j = 1
For i = 1 To d2
c = Mid(s2, i, 1)
Select Case c
Case "0" To "9", "A" To "Z"
a2 = a2 & c
j = j + 1
End Select
Next
If j = 1 Then Exit Function
d2 = j - 1
k = d1
If d2 < d1 Then 
'to prevent doubling the code below s1 must be made the shortest string,
'so we swap the variables
k = d2
d2 = d1
d1 = k
s1 = a2
s2 = a1
a1 = s1
a2 = s2
Else
s1 = a1
s2 = a2
End If
If k = 1 Then 'degenerate case, where the shortest string is just one character
If InStr(1, s2, s1, vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
Fuzzy = 1 / d2
Else
Fuzzy = 0
End If
Else '******* MAIN LOGIC HERE *******
i = 1
f = 0
o = 0
Do 'count the identical characters in s1 and s2 ("frequency analysis")
p = InStr(1, s2, Mid(s1, i, 1), vbBinaryCompare)
'search the character at position i from s1 in s2
If p > 0 Then 'found a matching character, at position p in s2
f = f + 1 'increment the frequency counter
s2 = Left(s2, p - 1) & "~" & Mid(s2, p + 1)
'replace the found character with one outside the allowable list
'(I used tilde here), to prevent re-finding
Do 'check the order of characters
If i >= k Then Exit Do 'no more characters to search
If Mid(s2, p + 1, 1) = Mid(s1, i + 1, 1) Then
'test if the next character is the same in the two strings
f = f + 1 'increment the frequency counter
o = o + 1 'increment the order counter
i = i + 1
p = p + 1
Else
Exit Do
End If
Loop
End If
If i >= k Then Exit Do
i = i + 1
Loop
If o > 0 Then o = o + 1 'if we got at least one match, adjust the order counter
'because two characters are required to define "order"
finish:
w = 2 'Weight of characters order match against characters frequency match;
'feel free to experiment, to get best matching results with your data.
'If only frequency is important, you can get rid of the second Do...Loop
'to significantly accelerate the code.
'By altering a bit the code above and the equation below you may get rid
'of the frequency parameter, since the order counter increments only for
'identical characters which are in the same order.
'However, I usually keep both parameters, since they offer maximum flexibility
'with a variety of data, and both should be maintained for this project
Fuzzy = (w * o + f) / (w + 1) / d2
End If
End Function
```

==================

So once you have it then just add something like this.

```
Dim strA, strB, hiScore(1 to 3), tempScore

With Thisworkbook.ActiveSheet
    For a = 1 to .Usedrange.Rows.Count ' Scans Column 1
        strA = .cells(a,1) ' Barclays Aggregate Index
        For b = 1 to .usedrange.rows.count ' Compares Col 1 to Col 2
            strB = .cells(b,2) ' Barclays Aggregate Other Index
            tempScore = Fuzzy(strA, strB)
            If tempScore > hiScore then
                hiScore(1) = tempScore
                hiScore(2) = a 
                hiScore(3) = b
            End If 
        Next b
        ' Do your Action with the Best Match Here
        If hiScore(1) = 1 then ' (100% - perfect match)
            ' Copies col 3 from the row that the best strB match was on 
            ' to col 4 from the row strA was on
            .Cells(a,4) = .Cells(hiScore(3),3)
        End If
        ' ====
        ' Reset Variables
        hiScore = ""
        tempScore = ""
    Next a
End with
```

Comment: how do i add this code? does it run in a separate subroutine that I call before running this sub, or do I call it within?

Answer (score 0):

Comment as answer because I cannot comment:

Aren't you looking for the `Like` operator? 
And you should add to the top of your code: `Option compare text`

[More info on the like operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx)